# How to set an Oracle user's default schema?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I created a few new users in Oracle.  However, when running sqlplus, they all need to fully qualified the table names in query.  What's the best way to set a default schema for these new users?

Answer (score 23):

There is nothing like PostgreSQL's `set search_path` in Oracle.

The closest thing I can think of would be a logon trigger for the user that run's an `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA ...`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOGON_TRG 
  AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = foobar';
EXCEPTION 
  when others 
    then null; -- prevent a login failure due to an exception
END;
/
```

If the list of users isn't too long, you can create a database logon trigger so you don't have to create that trigger for each user:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOGON_TRG 
  AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
    if (user in ('TOM', 'DICK', 'HARRY')) then
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = foobar';
    end if;
exception 
  when others 
    then null; -- prevent a login failure due to an exception
END logon_trg;
/
```

Of course the list of users where you want to change the default schema, can also be taken from a table. In that case you only need to insert or delete rows from there in order to "activate" this feature (rather than re-creating the trigger each time).

Another option would be to create synonyms each time you create user that point to the real tables. You could automate that using a stored procedure that loops through all tables in one schema and creates the synonyms for them in the other schema.

Unless ***all*** your Oracle users work on the same tables I would strongly advise against using *public* synonyms which you would have to create only once - they can cause a lot of trouble if different application users exist in your installation.

**Edit**:

Following Alex's suggestion, here is a logon trigger that checks the role rather than a username:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOGON_TRG
  AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
declare
  has_role boolean;
BEGIN

    has_role := dbms_session.is_role_enabled('FOOBAR_ROLE');

    if (has_role) then
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = foobar';
    end if;
exception 
   when others 
      then null; -- prevent a login failure due to an exception    
END logon_trg;
/
```

Comment: Great idea but since `when others then null;` is a catch-all, it will complicate troubleshooting since it makes any error invisible.  Maybe remove the exception handling entirely or [log the error on the server in an AUTONOMOUS transaction and then re-RAISE it](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/09/classic-example-of-why-i-despise.html)?

Comment: @George3: but if the exception is actually thrown, the user cannot log in - I just wanted to prevent someone being not able to log in just because of a stupid mistaked in the trigger. But anyone is free to adapt this to whatever he/she wants.

Answer (score 1):

After starting SQLPlus, [there is a `glogin.sql`, and a `login.sql` script that is run](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1168761).
You can put:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=YOUR_SCHEMA;
```

in either, and they will be run.

The `login.sql` needs to be in a directory set by an environment variable: `SQLPATH`, and the `glogin.sql` is in the same directory as `sqlplus.exe` is installed into.
I couldn't get the `login.sql` part working, but the `glogin.sql` script executed fine.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldnt think there is a way to set one. The user is the schema.
AFAIK you can only set default tablespace.